# ghostscript settings to open PDF as full page

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I know from some colleagues, who are desiging our leaflets in Indesign and store as PDF's that there is a setting to view it in full page mode, when opening the file.

I did a script to "merge" some of these docs using ghostscript device -pdfwriter and option -dPDFFitPage (edited after KenS' answer)

here my full command:

```
gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNO_PDFMARK_OUTLINES -dPDFFitPage -o output.pdf cover.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf input3.pdf pdfmarks
```

But "-dPDFFitPage" does not do what I am expecting. The pagewidth is fit on screen, but I would like the whole page to fit on screen. I also heard using "/FIT" in the pdfmarks would help but it also doesn't.

If anybody can help me, I would be very thankful.

Best regards

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some other hours of reading the pdfmark reference and asking google various questions, I came across my ultimate and satisfying solution:

```
[ /PageMode /UseOutlines /Page 1 /View [ /Fit] /PageLayout /SinglePage /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

So I simply added /PageLayout /SinglePage and it opens in full page mode in the reader window, showing bookmarks (/UseOutlines) and when scrolling, it scrolls pagewise, so every step of the mouswheel is one page. This works perfectly now.

Comment: Special thanks to KenS who put me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, perhaps it will help other's so I am posting it as an answer. KenS' answer was a big help to solve my problem. Thanks to him.

```
    [ /PageMode /UseOutlines
      /Page 1 /View [/Fit]
      /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

This sets the magnification of the PDF file to "windows size". With Acrobat Reader and Acrobat standard, it works pretty well. Other readers are not tested.

Best regards

Mike

Answer (score 0):

There is no option -dpdfwriter. The fact that PDFFitPage doesn't do what you want isn't surprising, it has no effect on what a PDF viewer will do. This option (which is described in the documentation) only has any effect when used with a pre-defined fixed media size. It creates a new PDF where the content of the original PDF is scaled so that fits onto the fixed media size.

If you want to include directions to PDF viewers on how to open PDF documents then you need to look at the pdfmark operator. Specifically you will need to construct a DOCVIEW pdfmark as described on page 29 and 30 of the version 9 pdfmark reference.

Comment: Dear KenS, actually, I am using podfmark reference 8, dtd. November 2006. After searching Adobe's website, I cam across the pdfmark reference Version May 2015 in the Acrobat DC SDK but it tell to be version 2.0. However, in both version is the DOCVIEW described on page 29/30 which I actually consulted before. FullScreen goes in my desired direction, however, I wish to see it inside PDF reader and not fullscreen mode. "Fullpage" describes best what I want, however, this does not exist.

Comment: Dear KenS, sure you are right. Actually pdfwrite is not an option but a device. I've corrected my question. I've made some tests with fixed media size in the past, but it gives me non satisfactory results: I am merging different page sizes to 01 document. A lot of Documents in format A4 and some drawings in Format A1 or even A0. And I do not want to have it scaled to A4. the original size should stay as it was, so I deleted the fixedmedia option again.

Comment: Well I'm afraid pdfwrite can only put into the PDF file the things that are in the specification. And even then, only if the PDF viewer supports it. You haven't said what you are using for a viewer. Possibly I simply don't understand what it is you are asking for, but I don't see this as a Ghostscript problem.

Comment: Well I do not yet know if it is a ghostscript problem or a pdfmark problem. In my eyes there are 2 possible ways for solving it and I thought (was hoping) ghostscript could do. 

In the meantime, I implemented a workaround and use the zoom-factor in pdfmark to scale to 70% 
`/Page 1 /View [/XYZ null null 0.7]`
This is working well for all screens with FULL HD resolution. But some other screens are different, like MS Surface, etc. 

We are using Acrobat Reader DC Version 2018.011.20063

Comment: By the way KenS, I realised you are pretty active in PDF / hostscript / pdfmark. Do you know some good websites, besides the offical pdfmark rederences, to get more detailed in the subject? I am not a programmer but doing those "things" besides my normal job in the sales and all I know was learning by doing. I feel pdfmark a very mighty tool and I am using only less than 1% of what it can do...

Comment: The pdfmark references are all there is, because that specification is still owned by Adobe, its not been adopted by the ISO. You can read the PDF Reference Manual to see what options are available (not every possible value in a PDF file has a corresponding pdfmark) For example there are 6 possible PageMode values defined, but the pdfmark reference only lists 4. The extra are UseOC and UseAttachments.

Comment: There does not seem to be any option to open the document fuilscreen, and at the same time set the ZoomFactor to Page Level. Possibly you could set the Open mode to FullScreen and set a destination of [/Page 1 /Fit] instead of an XYZ destination.

Comment: [ /Page 1 /View [/Fit] was the solution. I just posted my answer.Thanks for your help. But what I really would like to set is the "Page Layout".: When using /Fit the magnification is set to Window Size. Wen scrolling, next page comes from the bottom. When seting (in Acrobat Standard) the "Page Layout" to "Single Page", it looks the same when opening, but when scrolling, you just "jump" to the next page. You do not see it scrolling in from the bottom. It has the advantage that it always is filling the window size and not 50% of page 1 and 50% of page 2. But this is a minor probelm.

Comment: There doesn't appear (currently) to be a pdfmark to set Page Layout as such. However you can use the /PUT pdfmark to put arbitrary key/value pairs into dictionaries, and the Catalog dictionary is a predefined named object. See for example the second to last example on page 16 of the 9.0 pdfmark reference. You should be able to PUT a /PageLayout key with a name object as a value. Eg [{Catalog} <</PageLayout /OneColumn>> /PUT pdfmark